# Is there a way to create interactive R document without Shiny Server or the user having R?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, interactive

If I want to send emails with html documents included, but the end users do not have R, and we do not have a Shiny Server, is there a way to still make these documents interactive?

I am unsure if HTML widgets would work or not as well.

Comment: Have you tried using `plotly` and rendering with `self_contained: true` in the top yaml? Relevant: https://moderndata.plot.ly/r-markdown-and-knitr-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: If you want only simple filtering of data (in tables and/or graphs) you might look at [crosstalk](http://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/) but the possibilities are much narrower than with shiny